# Angular Material Navigate rows using up and down arrow key

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-class, mat-table

I added a custom `ngclass` to my mat-table to to make the rows clickable. but now I would like the user to be able to navigate using the up and down arrow keys. using this git hub as a reference(https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14861) I was able to get it to work on the first try by using the `tabindex` to capture  the keydown event. But I have not been able to find out why it only works on the first try; Here is the stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/arrownavigation?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

**.HTML**

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;  let i= index"
    [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.position}"
    (click)="highlight(row, i)"
    tabindex="999"
    (keydown.arrowdown)="arrowDownEvent(row, i)"
    (keydown.arrowup)="arrowUpEvent(row, i)"></tr>
</table>
```

**.TS**

```
highlight(row: any){
    this.selectedRowIndex = row.position;
    console.log(row);
  }

   arrowUpEvent(row: object, index: number){
    var nextrow = this.dataSource[index - 1];
    this.highlight(nextrow);
  }

  arrowDownEvent(row: object, index: number){
    var nextrow = this.dataSource[index + 1];
     this.highlight(nextrow);
    console.log(index);
  }
```

**.CSS**

```
.highlight{
  background: yellow;
}

tr:focus{
      outline: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the issues and now it's working. See this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/arrownavigation-9qz7d5?file=app/table-basic-example.html

The major problem was, you were passing 'i' in arrowDownEvent and arrowUpEvent where you should've passed selectedRowIndex.Then, your defined array is 0-indexed, but index 'i' in *matRowDef was 1-indexed. So I had to change some logic in arrowDownEvent and arrowUpEvent to solve this problem

Comment: This is actually easier to do. See this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/arrownavigation-fjae3p?file=app/table-basic-example.html